# Protractor test timing out after login

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Working on my first angular app, and writing my first protractor test to check login functionality. Authentication is using ng-token-auth and I'm also using ui-router. I suspect the issue is that the test is not properly catching the redirect but I've tried various workarounds and cannot get anything to work.

Here's the basic routing and redirection code:

```
angular
  .module('testAngularApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ui.router',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ng-token-auth'
  ])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $authProvider.configure({
      apiUrl: 'http://backend.dev'
    });

    $stateProvider
      .state('index', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      })
      .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        resolve: {
          auth: function($auth, $state) {
            return $auth.validateUser().catch(function() {
              $state.go('index');
            });
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'dashboard'
      });
  })
  .run(function($rootScope, $location, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('auth:login-success', function() {
      $state.go('app.dashboard');
    });
  });
```

So on rendering the main page, you fill in login details, click the button, and use $state.go to head to the app dashboard. My protractor test is as follows:

```
describe('Budget', function() {
  describe('Authentication', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('http://localhost:9000');
    });

    it('should log in and redirect to the dashboard', function(done) {
      element(by.model('loginForm.email')).sendKeys('someone@somewhere.com');
      element(by.model('loginForm.password')).sendKeys('password');
      element(by.id('login-button')).click();

      expect($('h3.title').getText()).toEqual('Welcome');
    });
  });
});
```

Fairly straightforward. The error I get is:

```
     Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md. The following tasks were pending:
- $timeout: function () {
                    return _this.validateUser({
                      config: _this.getSavedConfig()
                    });
                  }
```

Notably as this test fails, it works just fine. In the chrome window that pops up, logging in works, the browser redirects and I see the Welcome text.

Things I've tried...

- browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; in the test
- browser.wait(...for element...) in the test
- $location.path instead of $state.go
- adding browser.waitForAngular() to the test
- probably random other stack overflow suggestions I've found and forgotten

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out. For reference it seems to be an issue with ng-token-auth using a $timeout variable in some of it's code that confuses progractor. Fixed in this PR:

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth/pull/196

and verified fixed in the 0.29beta1 release.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue using ui-router and ng-token-auth, but I finally got it resolved with a mix of those options; Try this:

```
it('should log in and redirect to the dashboard', function(done) {
  element(by.model('loginForm.email')).sendKeys('someone@somewhere.com');
  element(by.model('loginForm.password')).sendKeys('password');
  element(by.id('login-button')).click();

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.waitForAngular();
  browser.sleep(5000);

  $('h3.title').getText().then(function(text){
    expect(text).toEqual('Welcome');
  });

  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```

I think this could be because of a bug in ng-token-auth, but I'm not 100% sure.

*edit*: it was a bug in ng-token-auth, fixed in the latest version(v0.0.29-beta1)

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work for me though but I did figure it out, see my answer if you still have problems.

Comment: @Chad Thanks! That fixed all my errors. I figured the issue was within ng-token-auth.

Comment: This wait fixed errors I was getting in protractor as I couldn't change application code